Writing comments spring boot
I'm building a Spring Boot app similar to YouTube, I can successfully upload videos but I can't write comments or like and dislike reactions, and for some reason the thumbnail I uploaded with the video is not showing up
so this is my home controller

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @Autowired
    private VideoRepository videoRepository;

    @Autowired
    private VideoService videoService;


    @GetMapping("/springtube")
    public String home(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("videos", videoRepository.findAll());
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        boolean isAuthenticated = auth.isAuthenticated();
        model.addAttribute("isAuthenticated", isAuthenticated);
        return "home";
    }



    @GetMapping("/video_detail")
    public String videoDetailPage() {
        return "video_detail"; // Return the video_detail.html template
    }


    @GetMapping("/files/{file-name:.+}")
    public void getFile(@PathVariable("file-name") String fileName, HttpServletResponse response){
        Video video = videoService.findByStorageName(fileName);
        if (video == null) {
            // Handle file not found
            return;
        }
        if (fileName.endsWith("_thumbnail")) {
            videoService.writeThumbnailToResponse(video.getThumbnailUrl(), response);
        } else {
            videoService.writeFileToResponse(fileName, response);
        }
    }
}

Video model


@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Data
public class Video {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String originalName;
    private String storageFileName;
    private String url;
    private Long size;
    private String type;
    private String thumbnailUrl;


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "channel_id")
    private Channel channel;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "video")
    private Set<Comment> comments = new HashSet<>();
}



@Controller
public class VideoController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    @Autowired
    private VideoService videoService;

    @GetMapping("/channel")
    public String showUploadForm(Model model, Principal principal) {
        // Fetch the authenticated user's channel
        String email = principal.getName();
        Optional<User> optionalUser = userRepository.findByEmail(email);
        if (optionalUser.isPresent()) {
            User user = optionalUser.get();
            List<Video> userVideos = videoService.getUploadedVideos(user.getId());
            model.addAttribute("videos", userVideos);// Add a new Video object to the model);
            model.addAttribute("channelName", user.getChannel().getName()); // Add channel name
            return "upload"; // Returns the upload form HTML page
        }
        return "redirect:/error";
    }

    @PostMapping("/channel")
    public String handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
                                   @RequestParam("thumbnail") MultipartFile thumbnail,
                                   Principal principal) {
        // Validate the uploaded files
        if (file.isEmpty() || thumbnail.isEmpty()) {
            return String.valueOf(ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Please select both video and thumbnail files."));
        }

        videoService.saveFile(file, thumbnail, principal);

        return "redirect:/channel";
    }
}


@Repository
public interface VideoRepository extends JpaRepository<Video, Long> {
    Video findByStorageFileName (String fileName);
}


public interface VideoService {

    Video findById(Long id);

    String saveFile(MultipartFile uploadFile, MultipartFile thumbnailFile, Principal principal);
    void writeFileToResponse(String fileName, HttpServletResponse response);
    Video findByStorageName(String storageName);
    List<Video> getUploadedVideos(Long userId);
    void writeThumbnailToResponse(String fileName, HttpServletResponse response);
}



@Component
public class VideoServiceImpl implements VideoService {

    @Autowired
    private VideoRepository videoRepository;
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Value("${storage.path}")
    private String storagePath;

    @Override
    public Video findById(Long id) {
        return videoRepository.findById(id).get();
    }




    @Override
    public String saveFile(MultipartFile uploadFile, MultipartFile thumbnailFile, Principal principal) {
        String email = principal.getName();
        Optional<User> optionalUser = userRepository.findByEmail(email);
        if (optionalUser.isPresent()) {
            User user = optionalUser.get();
            Channel channel = user.getChannel();
            if (channel != null) {
                String videoExtension = FilenameUtils.getExtension(uploadFile.getOriginalFilename());
                String thumbnailExtension = FilenameUtils.getExtension(thumbnailFile.getOriginalFilename());

                String videoStorageName = UUID.randomUUID().toString() + "." + videoExtension;
                String thumbnailStorageName = UUID.randomUUID().toString() + "_thumbnail." + thumbnailExtension;

                try {
                    String videoFullPath = Paths.get("src/main/resources", storagePath, videoStorageName).toString();
                    String thumbnailFullPath = Paths.get("src/main/resources", storagePath, thumbnailStorageName).toString();

                    Files.createDirectories(Paths.get(videoFullPath).getParent()); // Create directories if they don't exist
                    Files.createDirectories(Paths.get(thumbnailFullPath).getParent()); // Create directories if they don't exist

                    Files.copy(uploadFile.getInputStream(), Paths.get(videoFullPath));
                    Files.copy(thumbnailFile.getInputStream(), Paths.get(thumbnailFullPath));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to save files", e);
                }

                Video video = Video.builder()
                        .type(uploadFile.getContentType())
                        .originalName(uploadFile.getOriginalFilename())
                        .size(uploadFile.getSize())
                        .storageFileName(videoStorageName)
                        .url(storagePath + "/" + videoStorageName)
                        .thumbnailUrl(storagePath + "/" + thumbnailStorageName) // Set the thumbnail URL
                        .channel(channel)
                        .build();

                videoRepository.save(video);

                return video.getStorageFileName();
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to save files: User's channel not found");
    }


    @Override
    public void writeFileToResponse(String fileName, HttpServletResponse response) {
        Video fileInfo = videoRepository.findByStorageFileName(fileName);
        if (fileInfo == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("File not found with name: " + fileName);
        }
        response.setContentType(fileInfo.getType());
        try {
            IOUtils.copy(new FileInputStream("src/main/resources"+"/"+fileInfo.getUrl()), response.getOutputStream());
            response.flushBuffer();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public Video findByStorageName(String storageName) {
        return videoRepository.findByStorageFileName(storageName);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Video> getUploadedVideos(Long userId) {
        return null;
    }



    @Override
    public void writeThumbnailToResponse(String fileName, HttpServletResponse response) {
        Video thumbnailVideo = videoRepository.findByStorageFileName(fileName);
        if (thumbnailVideo == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Thumbnail file not found with name: " + fileName);
        }
        response.setContentType("image/png"); // Assuming thumbnails are JPEG images
        try {
            // Read the thumbnail image from file and write it to the response output stream
            IOUtils.copy(new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/" + thumbnailVideo.getThumbnailUrl()), response.getOutputStream());
            response.flushBuffer();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error writing thumbnail to response", e);
        }
    }

}

home.js

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    // Get all video items
    const videoItems = document.querySelectorAll('.video-item');

    // Add click event listener to each video item
    videoItems.forEach(videoItem => {
        videoItem.addEventListener('click', function() {
            // Extract video ID or storage file name from data attribute
            const videoId = this.getAttribute('data-video-id');

            // Construct URL for video detail page with parameters
            const videoDetailURL = `/video_detail.ftlh?videoId=${videoId}`;

            // Redirect user to video detail page
            window.location.href = videoDetailURL;
        });
    });
});

video_detail
<main>
    <div class="video-container">
    </div>
    <div class="video-actions">
        <!-- Like, dislike, and subscribe buttons -->
        <button class="like-btn"><i class="fas fa-thumbs-up"></i> Like</button>
        <button class="dislike-btn"><i class="fas fa-thumbs-down"></i> Dislike</button>
        <button class="subscribe-btn"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i> Subscribe</button>
    </div>
    <div class="comment-section">

    </div>
</main>

knowing that the thumbnail is being saved successfully but

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

That is a lot of code. Have you been able to narrow down where the problem is happening? Your question ends in an incomplete sentence. Did it get cut off? A couple of architectural notes: Having repositories in the controller is an anti-pattern. The controller should be delegating that work to the service layer. Adding all videos to the model is crazy unless this is intended to always be a small project with only a small number of videos, but I assume that's the case.
